# SensorTag, iBeacon, Compiled firmware doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, iar, texas-instruments

Followed the instruction at http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_with_iBeacon.
The iBeacon-enabled firmware was created with IAR and updated with OAD from iPhone but SensorTag stopped working after the update. No advertising, no LED blink by the side button.

I tried same/similar things several times and also tried directly upload the firmware from IAR IDE via CC Debugger but no luck.

I can put it back to the previous working state by uploading downloaded firmware with the flash programmer.

I also tried to compile the standard firmware (SensorTag with no iBeacon from the BLE stack) by myself with the IAR but it didn't work, neither.

So I think the compiling in IAR is my problem but the make could finish successfully. No code was changed by myself. (only the _NR_OF_VIRTUAL_REGISTERS to avoid a linker error).

I wonder if there are anyone who successfully made it work by following the instruction on the above URL.

1. Firmware for iBeacon: SensorTag_Beacon_Patch_1v0
2. CC Debugger's FW:0041
3. SensorTag: CC2451, 1.4.1, 1407
4. IAR for 8051 version 8.30.3
5. BLE stack: BLE_CC254x_140.zip
6. Working standard firmware version: 1.5 A & B

If I could get any suggestions or advises, it'd be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Are you building a CC2541 version of the project, or perhaps a CC2540 version?  Do the available memory settings of your project configuration match that in the chip you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment, Chris.

I found a solution on TI E2E community.

IAR 8051 V8.30 has a problem since updated from V8.20. It was reported as "8051 V8.30 linker Error[e16]: Segment ISTACK is too long for segment definition" (http://supp.iar.com/Support/?Note=95811).

After modifications to .xcl linker configuration, the build ran OK without any errors.
But the firmware didn't work on SensorTag.

One of the post on TI E2E Community mentioned that changing the Number of virtual registers in the "Option" settings from 16 to 12 worked with IAR V8.30.3. Then tried that with an original .xcl file (not modified one). No error during build and worked on SensorTag too.

There are 3 packages in the SensorTag_Beacon project, that are CC2541DK-Sensor, CC2541DK-Sensor-OAD-ImgA and CC2514DK-Sensor-OAD-ImgB.
What worked are only CC2541DK-Sensor with Number of Virtual Register in Option set to 12 and without .xcl file modified.

CC2541DK-Sensor-OAD-ImgA and CC2514DK-Sensor-OAD-ImgB didn't work with any combinations of the Option setting and .xcl modifications.

Hope this helps to anyone else in the future.

Regards,